# How to make Javascript collapsible to work and show content by default?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to make this collapsible work by pressing the +/- button. I would like it to work so that it's showing by default and you can hide it by pressing the button. At the moment nothing happens from the button.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 10%;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="whoami">
  <div class="popup-header">
  <div class="popup-bar">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum<h3/>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible"></button>
  </div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML syntax is wrong; a closing tag looks like this `</h3>` and you cannot put classes in it (or other attributes). Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/x45pwyhq/

Comment: Hi, it's usually really helpful to look at your browser's console log. In this case when I ran your snippet I found an error at </div class="content"> - a typo I expect, an unwanted forward slash. If you take that out do you still have a problem?

Comment: Ugh of course there were typos. Man I was blind. But still not working :/ console log states an error in another situation, but not this.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum</summary>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. 
</details>
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

the same, with styling "old school"

```js
// set it open at start :
document.querySelector('details').open = true;
```

```css
details {
  border  : 1px solid lightgrey;
  width   : 29em;
  padding : .5em;
  }
summary {
  position      : relative;
  font-weight   : bold;
  margin-bottom : .4em;
  list-style    : none;
  }
summary::marker {
  display : none;
  }
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display : none;
  }
summary::after {
  position    : absolute;
  top         : -.2em;
  right       : -.2em;
  display     : block;
  border      : 1px solid grey;
  text-align  : center;
  width       : 1.5em;
  height      : 1.5em;
  line-height : 1.5em;
  content     : '\02795';
  cursor      : pointer;
  border-radius: .2em;
  }
details[open] > summary:after {
  content     : '\2796';
  }
summary:focus,
summary:hover {
  outline: none;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Lorem ipsum</summary>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, 
    dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas 
    ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, 
    enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae,
    consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. 
    Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. 
  </details>
```

Comment: My main goal is to style it like an old school computer window so the action needs to happen from the button. Otherwise this would be perfect

Comment: @casualminna  completed with styling for a button

Comment: Wow thanks! I guess it's not possible to make it so that the button only has the action without removing the title?

Comment: @casualminna Indeed the whole `summary` element serves as a trigger. We cannot change that.